# What grammatical label can be given to the word "gone "in this sentence

Tags: grammar

> My mother promised to look after my dog while I was gone.

Can someone through light upon the above given sentence
What grammatical label can be given to the word "gone."
Also is the sentence grammatically correct ?

Comment: I'd say it's a past participle verb form used adjectivally. Same as *continuous* participle being used adjectivally in, say, *She promised to look after my dog while I was **working***. Or a straightforward adjective, such as *...while I was **ill***.

Comment: Would you like to make it an answer to get it off the homepage?

Answer (score 3):

It's an adjective here.

***GONE***

ADJECTIVE

No longer present; departed.

‘you were gone a long time’

‘the bad old days are gone’

([Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gone) )

Comment: Thanks, is the sentence in discussion grammatically correct?

Comment: It is grammatically correct.